# Sending query parameters to a POST request laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I wish to send a query like string to a POST request, this string is in a variable called `$info`

```
 $info = firstname=testing123&lastname=testing123&email=testing13@gmail.com&number=123
```

So my routes will be like this

```
Route::post('/action/{date}/{time}/{info}', 'Action@confirm');
```

And my form like this

```
<form action="/confirmation/{{$date}}/{{$time}}/{{$info}}" method="POST"> 
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      <input type="text" name="action" required>
      <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
```

I cannot pass the `$info` variable, I get a `No such file or directory` error.

How can I pass a query like string to a POST request using routes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query parameters do not need to be defined in the route. So you can remove the `info` parameter from the route definition.

```
Route::post('/action/{date}/{time}', 'Action@confirm');
```

Then add the query string to your `action` on the form

```
<form action="/confirmation/{{$date}}/{{$time}}?{{$info}}" method="POST"> 
    ...
</form>
```

And in the controller you can access the data the same way you would any other parameter

```
$firstname= $request->get('firstname');
```

Alternatively I would consider a different way of transmitting that data. From what you've provided it looks like might be more appropriate to store that data in the session then retrieve it from the session in the `Action@confirm` method.

Comment: There you go, such a simple solution, I actually made a hidden input and passed the `$info` variable and requested from the controller, thank you, this was bugging me for a long time.